# Magento 2 how to add images to recently ordered / reorder products block in the sidebar

Tags: magento2, sidebar, reorder

How can we include product images in the recently ordered items block located in the sidebar? By default its only showing a checkbox and the product name

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add images to the reorder block we should provide them to knockout

Override **Magento\Sales\CustomerData\LastOrderedItems** in a custom module, change the items array in the getItems method to include an image:

```
$items[] = [
    'id' => $item->getId(),
    'name' => $item->getName(),
    'url' => $url,
    'is_saleable' => $this->isItemAvailableForReorder($item),
    'image' => $this->getImageData($product)
];
```

And a method to generate the image data (adapted from wishlist):

```
protected function getImageData($product)
{
    /*Set variant product if it is configurable product.
    It will show variant product image in sidebar instead of configurable product image.*/
    $simpleOption = $product->getCustomOption('simple_product');
    if ($simpleOption !== null) {
        $optionProduct = $simpleOption->getProduct();
        $product = $optionProduct;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $helper */
    $helper = $this->imageHelperFactory->create()
        ->init($product, 'wishlist_sidebar_block');

    $template = $helper->getFrame()
        ? 'Magento_Catalog/product/image'
        : 'Magento_Catalog/product/image_with_borders';

    try {
        $imagesize = $helper->getResizedImageInfo();
    } catch (NotLoadInfoImageException $exception) {
        $imagesize = [$helper->getWidth(), $helper->getHeight()];
    }

    $width = $helper->getFrame()
        ? $helper->getWidth()
        : $imagesize[0];

    $height = $helper->getFrame()
        ? $helper->getHeight()
        : $imagesize[1];

    return [
        'template' => $template,
        'src' => $helper->getUrl(),
        'width' => $width,
        'height' => $height,
        'alt' => $helper->getLabel(),
    ];
}
```

Then we override module-sales/view/frontend/templates/reorder/sidebar.phtml to include the image:

```
<a class="product-item-photo" data-bind="attr: { href: url, title: name }">
    <!-- ko template: {name: $data.image.template, data: $data.image} --><!-- /ko -->
</a>
```